# Letterpress effect for UILabel in iOS 7 SDK

Tags: ios, uilabel, ios7, textkit, letterpress

In the WWDC 2013 videos they show that a developer can use a letterpress effect on text.
Does anyone have any example code of how to do this/how to do this with a UILabel?

Comment: Can you please accept the answer so it helps other as well? Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

They've made it pretty simple now.

```
//Use any font you want or skip defining it
UIFont* font = [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleHeadline];

//Use any color you want or skip defining it
UIColor* textColor = [UIColor blueColor];

NSDictionary *attrs = @{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : textColor,
                                NSFontAttributeName : font,
                          NSTextEffectAttributeName : NSTextEffectLetterpressStyle};

NSAttributedString* attrString = [[NSAttributedString alloc]
                                   initWithString:note.title
                                       attributes:attrs];

myTextLabel.attributedText = attrString;
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this with a UIButton?

Comment: Yes. You can use - (void)setAttributedTitle:(NSAttributedString *)title forState:(UIControlState)state

Comment: Thank you, it's working now I had a related error which prevented it from showing

Answer (score 0):

It's part of [NSAttributedString UIKitAdditions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSAttributedString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: That's not an answer.